# Boost c++ property - if key does not exist then set to false

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am new to json parsing with boost using the property tree.

If I have this hash:

```
foo = {'test1',true}

ptree pt;
bool v = pt.get<bool>("test2");
```

I need to check a key exists and if not set it to false.

How do I do that gracefully?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idm45506991683824-bb) you can try to find the key and if `not_found()` then you can push a new key.

> assoc_iterator not_found() ; Returns the not-found iterator.
>   Equivalent to end() in a real associative container.
>
> const_assoc_iterator not_found() const; Returns the not-found
>   iterator. Equivalent to end() in a real associative container.
>
> assoc_iterator find(const key_type & key) ; Find a child with the
>   given key, or not_found() if there is none. There is no guarantee
>   about which child is returned if multiple have the same key.
>
> const_assoc_iterator find(const key_type & key) const; Find a child
>   with the given key, or not_found() if there is none. There is no
>   guarantee about which child is returned if multiple have the same key.

Answer (score 6):

```
  // bool optional
  boost::optional<bool> v = pt.get_optional<bool>("test2");

  // any type actually
  boost::optional<std::string> v2 = pt.get_optional<std::string>("test3");

  if (v) // key exists
    bool bool_value = v.get();
  else // not exists
    v.set(false);
```

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that `boost::optional<std::string> v2 = pt.get_optional<std::string>("test3");` is allowed even if the value type of `test3` is not a string? (I've searched but can't find it.)